# difference between self and mean of the others in R

Tags: r

How can I make a matrix that represents difference between self and mean of the others? For example,

```
a<-c(1:60)
for (i in 1:60){ b<-(a[i]-mean(a[-i]))^2 }
```

however, this obvious solution doesn't work and produce `NA_Real_`

what does that mean? and how can i solve this?

Comment: `a - (sum(a) - a) / (length(a)-1)`

Comment: that's amazing...thanks a lot~:)